# Suggestion bar blackened

Tags: front-end

This is most likely a bug, but I am asking for a way around it without restarting Mathematica. It happens occasionally since v10 (ish, I can't pinpoint the exact version I observed it) and carries through to 11.2 on OSX. The screenshot below is from v11.2

[image: plot_blackened]

when Mathematica uses up a lot of memory, the suggestion bar goes black as above. The square brackets' zap effect (when they close) becomes very slow and restarting the Kernel fixes neither of these issues (the screenshot is on a fresh Kernel).

Is there something I can do to fix this without restarting Mathematica?

Comment: Since such behavior in my experience is usually shortly followed by a FE crash, immediately saving my work is the best thing I've come up with.  Crashing also supports the idea that it is a bug.